# Use build.finalizedBy on each subproject with Gradle kotlin

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to run a specific task after EVERY build of my subprojects. I can go into each of my subprojects `build.gradle.kts` file and add the following

```
tasks.build {
    finalizedBy("afterbuildtask")
}
```

However, this should be possible to do in my root project `build.gradle.kts` file right? I tried it by doing the following:

```
subprojects {
    this.tasks.findByName("build")?.dependsOn("afterbuildtask")
}
```

But nothing happens. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't programatically execute tasks from other tasks in newer versions of Gradle.
Instead, you are supposed to declare task dependencies and Gradle will ensure they get executed in the correct order. But I think it's not what you want

Alternatively, you could move your logic into the `doLast` block in the `build` task. eg:

```
build {
    doLast {
        println("Copying...")
        copy {
            from 'source'
            into 'target'
            include '*.war'
        }
        println("completed!")
    }
}
```

good coding! ¯_(ツ)_/¯